# how to convert type 'string' to 'string[]' in c#?

Tags: c#, xna

i have a bit of a problem with my code please can you help:

```
         String[] Boe;

         Boe = new String[1]; <---- i think the error might also be here 
         BS = new Rectangle();
         for (int p = 0; p < 1; p++)
         {
           //some code have been taken out 

             Boe = "Yes"; <----- this is where the error is being displayed 
         }
```

Comment: `Boe[0] = "Yes"` and REALLY no need for a `for` loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your trying to set the whole array as a simple string. You have to access the index of your array and then give this position a string value. 
Look down there

```
 String[] Boe;
 Boe = new String[1]; <---- i think the error might also be here 
 BS = new Rectangle();
 for (int p = 0; p < 1; p++)
 {
   //some code have been taken out 

     Boe[p] = "Yes"; <----- this is where the error is being displayed 
 }
```

Hope it helps you !

Comment: In this case, I've given you a for loop, but @AndrejBratoz was right to only give you the indexer 0 since you only have a single value. You'll lose some performance because at the end of the for loop, you'll check again if you're still within range. The loop was given in case the sample code was just an example and you could need it in a near future in your software.